# How to write the data into json file for the following code below and i am getting the following errors any one help me whats wrong in my code

Tags: python, json

```py
import argparse
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
import json

def image_to_text(image):
    pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser("Image content into text")
    ap.add_argument("--input", required = True, help='path to input image')
    args = ap.parse_args()
    img = Image.open(args.input)
    print(img.size)
    xy_coords = np.flip(np.column_stack(np.where(np.array(img) >= 0)), axis = 1)
    value = np.hstack([xy_coords])
    print(value)
    list = value
    js = json.dumps(list)
    jsonfile = open("coordinates.json","w")
    jsonfile.write(js)
    jsonfile.close()
    print(image_to_text(img))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\Desktop\image\code.py", line 26, in <module>
    js = json.dumps(list)
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Unindented Python code cannot be run and does not make sense.

Comment: sorry for that Can u look now i have edited the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, never use a function name as a variable name. By assigning a variable as list you just overridden your list function which you'll need. So use some better variable names.

The problem:

The error says it all.

```
TypeError: Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable
```

A json data can carry values of type of:

- string
- number
- object
- array
- true
- false
- null

see [Introducing JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

In your code you are trying to add a list or the data as below:

```
value = np.hstack([xy_coords])
print(value)
list = value
js = json.dumps(list)
```

You are trying to dump the `list`, which is pointed to the `value` which is a `numpy.ndarray` not a `list`. Json does support the `list` type but does not support `numpy.ndarray`.

So change the type of variable named `list` to list.

Comment: i did the following modification to convert to list but am getting attribute error: 'tuple' object has no attribute                                                                                                                               xy_coords = np.flip(np.column_stack(np.where(np.array(img)).tolist()), axis = 1)

Comment: Now you converted your data too early. Just convert the list variable to a type of list inside the json.dumps and leave other parts untouched.

Comment: Is this what ur conveying?                                                                                                                        js = json.dumps(List.tolist())